# How can I add a trailing space to a folder name?

Tags: html, windows, iis

Good day All,

A mix-up at the printers (or on our end) has resulted in a very costly print run of some business cards looking at the wrong url (using QR Codes).

The problematic url is structured as follows: **http://www.genericsite.com/a/b/c/d /e.pdf** . I have been looking around, but unfortunately come up empty on a way to add a trailing space to directory "d". The site in question is using Windows Server 2003 SP 2 IIS 6.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction ideas on how I can force a trailing space (or perform a redirect).

Thanks in advance!

Addendum

The redirect was my initial thought, but I am unable to create a source document from which to redirect from, hence the need to add a trailing space.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to change the URL than the directory structure?

Comment: Since the business cards have been printed, I don't see a way around this. The original url should have looked like http://www.genericsite.com/a/b/c/de.pdf, but somewhere along the way a " /" got added. Since "/" is also an excepted character, I assumed the trailing space may be easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setup a redirect so that you don't have to change anything else. Set up a redirect from your misspelled address to the actual one. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736641%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Josh, I had looked into that before, but it appears that I still need to have a source from which to redirect from.

Comment: I've never used IIS tbh but from the link it seems as though there might be an option to use a virtual directory? You wouldnt actually have to create it, just set the redirect from it.

Comment: the other alternative is to put some script in the 404 page (if that's the error that appears) which checks the referrer url and if it's your spacey one then send it to the right place.

Comment: I did try the virtual directory trick earlier, but it still requires a valid directory name. Points for a sneaky approach :) .

Comment: in which case see my next comment :p

Comment: That 404 idea was clever Josh. Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a redirect on the webserver that will send any requests for http://www.genericsite.com/a/b/c/d /e.pdf to http://www.genericsite.com/a/b/c/de.pdf

I'm assuming this is for one URL

***edit***

This is pretty straight forward with apache so I'm surprised that it seems like you need a module for IIS.

Have a look at the rewrite module:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/664/using-url-rewrite-module-20/

You should be able to do something like:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="redirect bad url" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="a/b/c/d /e.pdf" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="a/b/c/de.pdf" redirectType="Permenant" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Correct, just the one URL. Unfortunately, I am unable to create a source document/directory from which to redirect from since the space and "/" are not allowed.

Comment: This was an option we debated, but our production server is still IIS 6. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think this whole issue has convinced my that Apache is definetly  a superior choice for web hosting, I can't believe such a simple thing was so hard to do...

Comment: This is one case where I will have to agree. On the flip side, I've had a lot of fun experimenting with different error handling on the 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the largest issue here is the fact that space is not a valid URL character. If the QR had replaced the '`...d /e`' with '`...d%20/e`' it would have worked to rename the directory to "d ". Otherwise, I think you may be SOL.

Comment: I believe the browser fills in the %20 regardless. The kicker here is that I cannot figure out how to add the space following the directory.